# How to implement Single Sign On using SAML without any third party?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I ma beginner on SAML and doing first time Single Sign On.
I have multiple applications on different domains and all applications are built with different technologies.

i want to implement Single Sign On using SAML. i dont want to use any third party.
if some have any solution or example project please share

thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is very broad. What identity management backend do you have (Active Directory? Kerberos? LDAP? a database? a file?). Also, this question is not really about programming so would be better asked on one of the other Stack Exchange sites, e.g., [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look at [Onelogin's Open Source SAML toolkits](https://www.onelogin.com/resources/saml-toolkits)

There are examples of PHP, Python, Java and Ruby apps.

P.S SAML is complex, don't try to implement it yourself...

Comment: I already have checked these TPAs, i want to implement SSO using SAML without using any third party...because clients often do not trust third parties to have access to their applications (security resons).

Comment: Onelogin SAML toolkits are open source and have no dependencies with OL platform. You can use it with any Identity Provider.

And no one except you will have access to the data managed by the toolkit.